# Bootstrapping Mongoose models with nested schemas

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Hello I'm having trouble initializing my Mongoose models with nested Schemas, you see, this is my server.

```
var express = require('express'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose');
  bootstrap = require('./lib/bootstrap.js');

var app = express();

// Connect to Mongo when the app initializes
mongoose.connect('dir');

// Config should go here
bootstrap.execute();

// Setting up the app
app.use('/events', require('./route/events.js'));

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, function() { 
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port); 
});
```

The way I'm doing this right now is with a bootstrap function:

```
module.exports = {

  execute: function() {

    // Bootstrap entities
    var entityFiles = fs.readdirSync("model");
    entityFiles.forEach(function(file) {
      require("../model" + file);
    }));

  }

}
```

But order matters since my schemas are somewhat like these two:

```
var Presentation = mongoose.model('Presentation'),

var eventSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  presentations: [Presentation.schema]
});

module.export = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

and

```
var presentationSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  dateTime: Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Presentation', presentationSchema);
```

As you see they depend on one another and these are only two of them. So this means some will be bootstrapped first than the others and undoubtedly throw errors.

Is there a better way to do this? what am I missing?

I thought of just using the schemas instead of the models while requiring them but then I would have to change my schema files to something like this:

```
var presentationSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    dateTime: Date
});

module.exports = (function() {
    mongoose.model('Presentation', presentationSchema);
    return presentationSchema;
})();
```

Which seems awfully hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why I avoid using the mongoose.model to load my models.

Instead of that, if you just require the model when you need it, it will work as expected:

```
var Presentation = require('./presentation');

var eventSchema = new Schema({
   ...
   presentations: [Presentation.schema]
});

module.export = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

Remember that Node.js [cache its modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats), so the first time you call the require, node will load your module from scratch. After this, it'll return the module from the internal cache.

Comment: On another note, why is it necessary to use "./x" instead of "x" while requiring?

Comment: Because if you require "x", it will look over the "node_modules" path, instead of the path of your current script.

You can look for a better local require strategy here: https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520